# Macro to Record users have read a document

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

Apologies if this is answered somewhere else, but i have searched and couldn't find anything.

I have been asked to create a way of tracking when users have read our policy documents and recording it. My initial thoughts were to have a macro button at the bottom of the policy document (in word) which the user clicks to confirm they have read it. This would then update a Excel spreadsheet, which would then insert a new line capturing the users name, the document name and a timestamp.

The team can then view who has read what etc. and delete the excel lines once they are up to date. The excel would of course be saved in a static location.

Unfortunately, my VB skills are pretty minimal, so i wouldn't know where to start. Can this be done? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try below

```
Sub save_tracking()
Dim XLapp As Excel.Application
Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook
Set XLapp = New Excel.Application

'turn off extra bits
Screen_ = XLapp.ScreenUpdating
XLapp.ScreenUpdating = False
Event_ = XLapp.EnableEvents
XLapp.EnableEvents = False
Alerts_ = XLapp.DisplayAlerts
XLapp.DisplayAlerts = False

'get username
un = Environ("username")

'open tracking workbook
Set xlWB = XLapp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Test Tacking.xlsx", False, False)

'save information
With xlWB.Sheets(1)
    If .Range("A2").Value = "" Then
    'no values yet
        .Range("A2").Value = un
        .Range("B2").Value = XLapp.Name
        .Range("C2").Value = Now()
    ElseIf .Range("A3").Value = "" Then
    '2nd
        .Range("A3").Value = un
        .Range("B3").Value = XLapp.Name
        .Range("C3").Value = Now()
    Else
    '>2 values
        .Range("A2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = un
        .Range("B2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = XLapp.Name
        .Range("C2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = Now()
    End If
End With

'restore settings to previous
XLapp.ScreenUpdating = Screen_
XLapp.EnableEvents = Event_
XLapp.DisplayAlerts = Alerts_

'save/close workbook
xlWB.Close True
XLapp.Quit
Set XLapp = Nothing


End Sub

Function Environ(Expression)
On Error GoTo Err_Environ

    Environ = VBA.Environ(Expression)

Exit_Environ:
    Exit Function

Err_Environ:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Resume Exit_Environ

End Function
```

Change the filename of xlWB to where your tracking sheet is stored. In the tracking sheet A1/B1/C1 is reserved for a heading and information will be stored in the first sheet.

Edit: Modified to run from another office program. You will need a reference to "Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library" the version may be different but that should be ok. Tools --> References. gets you to the references

Comment: thanks for this, i think this is really close to what I am after. I'm getting a 'User-defined type not defined' error on the Dim xlwb as Workbook line though - any ideas what would cause that?

Comment: are you running this from within Excel? or another program?

Comment: From inside a Word document

Comment: Sorry for delay. I have amended the code in my answer. Remember you will need to add the reference mentioned in the Edit at the bottom

Comment: thanks so much - this is almost there, one last little thing though. The second column being captured is the application name (in this case Excel) i'd like it to capture the name of the Word Document the macro is run from?

Comment: change the three instances of xlapp.name to thisdocument.Name and that should do it.

Comment: Thank you so much Sir - i really appreciate your help! I changed the thisdocument to ActiveDocument as it was recording the template name rather than the the actual document name, but it has worked perfectly. Thank you so so much!